# Am I allowed to ask questions about a game which is in closed beta?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a WoW: Warlords of Draenor beta key and I played the closed beta of BF: Hardline, so now I ask myself, if I ever have a problem during a closed beta, am I allowed to ask a question about it or not?